# How much will airline charge me to bring rims in flight?

Tags: rims, transportation, wheels

I wasn’t sure if I should ask here, or in the travel site. So here goes.

I’ll be flying domestically to Miami via Frontier Airlines.

If I buy two bike rims in Miami, how much will Frontier charge me to carry the rims in the flight?

Comment: Do you mean just the rim (the donut part), or the entire built wheel assembly? Also, are these special wheels or something? Why go through the expense and hassle if not?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt SE can help you.   Surely the airline would be the correct place to consult?     https://www.flyfrontier.com/travel/travel-info/bag-options/   seems to be a good starting point.

Comment: I agree, on travel.se we would have to ask quite a few questions but most likely, if the rims fit in hold luggage they will be charged as the airline charges luggage of that size and weight. I would not count on them fitting into carry-on luggage but if they fit they might still be accepted. 12" or 16" wheels are also called bike wheels if very rare for adult bikes.